# How to cat file created by other user?

Tags: powershell, ssh

I'm running SSH server and facing an issue which is likely permission related. I use two Windows 10 machines and firstly I did the following locally.

```
PS C:\Users\User-A> cd Shared
PS C:\Users\User-A\Shared> echo foo > foo.txt
PS C:\Users\User-A\Shared> ls 


    Directory: C:\Users\User-A\Shared


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2019/08/20     17:18             12 foo.txt


PS C:\Users\User-A\Shared> cat .\foo.txt
foo
```

Next I SSHed to another machine and did this.

```
PS C:\Users\User-A> ssh User-B@192.168.1.1
User-B@192.168.1.1's password:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.678]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

User-B@MY-LAPTOP C:\Users\User-B>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\User-B> cd Shared
PS C:\Users\User-B\Shared> ls 


    Directory: C:\Users\User-B\Shared


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a---l       2019/08/20     17:18           (12) foo.txt


PS C:\Users\User-B\Shared> cat .\foo.txt
cat : Cannot access to the file.
At line:1 char:1
+ cat .\foo.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Users\User-B\Shared\foo.txt:String) [Get-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

I couldn't `cat` foo.txt. I supposed the issue may permission related, then tried to give permission to `Everyone` but it didn't work. And I found something weird here:

```
PS C:\Users\User-B\Shared> ls.\foo.txt | Select Mode, Name, LinkType

Mode   Name    LinkType
----   ----    --------
-a---l foo.txt


PS C:\Users\User-B\Shared> echo bar > foo.txt
PS C:\Users\User-B\Shared> cat .\foo.txt
bar
```

LinkType is blank, overwrite is allowed and `cat` works after that. Could you please tell me why it behaves like this and how can I give a permission to `cat` file to another machine? `Shared` is a directory shared via Dropbox.

**Please note that the command may contain small typo or difference because I translated messages into English and I don't want to publish real usernames or hostnames that contain private information.**

Comment: the `L` in your`mode` listing means `l - Reparse point, symlink, etc.` - and i wonder how it could be a reparse point when `LinkType` is blank. i am confused ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 0):

This was Dropbox related issue. I'm using Smart Sync and a file that User-B tried to `cat` was Online-only content which doesn't exist on local machine. Switching file to Local content solved the issue.

https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/smart-sync

I realized `cat : Cannot access to the file.` meant File Not Found but how unfriendly message, I thought it can be a permission error.